How to overlay marginal violin plots?
Say, for the below example, I want to overlay the violin plots, as opposed to seeing them side by side. This is for plotly dash.
Many thanks.
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_length", y="sepal_width", color="species", 
                 marginal_x="violin", marginal_y="violin",
                  title="Click on the legend items!")
fig.show()

